# save custom field to database does not save value

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I've got the folling problem:

I've got a new database field ( made with upgrade script ) to api/user table.

Now it's showing the field, but when I enter a value, it will not save.

Table field in db is called: `ip_address`, code to show in adminhtml:

**File:** Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Api_User_Edit_Tab_Main

***I know, i know! Going to extend it later, first want it to work!***

```
$fieldset->addField('ip_address', 'text', array(
    'name'  => 'ip_address',
    'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('IP Adres'),
    'id'    => 'ip_address',
    'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('IP Adres'),
    'required' => true,
));
```

***Already TRIED/CHECKED:***
I already tried logging out and back in, flushing all caches possible in backend and even delete contents of var/cache folder.

When I change an other value, it saves correctly. So I think I'm missing something.

Post is good, ip_address is in `$data`.
`getData('ip_address')` is set. 
Also tried `setData('ip_address', getData['ip_address']))` and `setData('ip_address', $data['ip_address'])`, also did not work.
If I fill database field manually, it will return it in backend, so that's good too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/User.php` file

You'd add the logic you need for your custom field in `save()` method, as it looks for very concrete data & it is ignoring any other field than expected